# Get commiters in a repo using Github API

Tags: python, github, networkx

I am using [PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/MainClass.html) to develop a proyect with networkx that creates graphs taking all the contributors in some repos and using them as nodes. However, I am not able to get the commiters from a repo using that library. Is there a way to get the commiters? help is much appreciated

code that I have:

```
from github import Github
import networkx as nx



def make_graph(commiters):
    G = nx.complete_graph(commiters)
    return G

def merge_graphs(G1, G2):
    G = nx.complete_graph(G1.nodes() + G2.nodes())

token = (token)
g = Github(token)


for repo in g.get_user('user').get_repos():
   print(repo.name)
   repo.edit(has_wiki=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PyGithub docs](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.get_contributors) you need to use `get_contributors` method:

```
repo.get_contributors()
```

Comment: I got it, I am trying to print them but I only get "<github.PaginatedList.PaginatedList object at 0x000002720F6418B0>" objects, do you know how can I get the proper string?

Comment: you can get logins of the contributors by using `login` property: `[contributor.login for contributor in repo.get_contributors()]`